# Как спрятать блоки?

Tags: html, css

Делаю чатик, нужно как-то спрятать блоки старых сообщений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="chat-body">
    <div class="chat-body_messages">
        <span class="chat-body_message chat-body_user-message">
            Привет, я пользователь
        </span>
        <span class="chat-body_message chat-body_interlocutor-message">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit error, deserunt accusamus consequatur in provident saepe, corrupti, ullam possimus quod hic beatae doloribus ducimus veniam aliquid impedit. Odit doloremque ullam provident, reprehenderit nisi dolores quos impedit. Adipisci repudiandae maxime assumenda facilis porro illum temporibus, nemo, dolor similique quis quam animi.
        </span>
        <span class="chat-body_message chat-body_user-message">
            Привет, я пользователь
        </span>
        <span class="chat-body_message chat-body_user-message">
            Привет, я пользователь
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Chat body */
.chat-body_messages {
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.chat-body_message {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.chat-body_user-message {
    background-color: #3C9DD0;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.chat-body_interlocutor-message {
    background-color: #235B79;
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Показываем первые пять сообщений: `.chat-body_messages .chat-body_message:nth-of-type(n+6) {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

блоку `.chat-body_messages` добавил `overflow: scroll;`